# How do i use php operators to add these two post id?

Tags: php, wordpress

Anybody can help me with this block of code? I' m still learning php, and this is for wordpress.

How do i add another post id "1221" into this block of code for the same function as post 425?

```
$additional_classes[] = ( is_object( $main_topic ) && 425 != $post->ID && !is_singular( $Theme->News->post_type ) ) ? 'term-' . $main_topic->slug : '';
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be better to start without if-shorthand syntax to really understand whats happening in this line:

```
if( 
   is_object( $main_topic ) //checks, if $main_topic is an object
   && (1221 != $post->ID || 425 != $post->ID ) //checks, if $post->ID is NOT 1221 NOR 425
   && !is_singular( $Theme->News->post_type ) //checks, if post_type is NOT singular
) {
  $additional_classes[] = 'term-' . $main_topic->slug;
} else {
  $additional_classes[] = '';
}
```

If all three if-statements/conditions (`&&` operator) are fulfilled, `$additional_classes[]` will be set, otherwise its an empty string.

Comment: Actually i tried this and its works. Not sure if this should be the correct way. 

    $additional_classes[] = ( is_object( $main_topic ) && 425 && 1221 != $post->ID && !is_singular( $Theme->News->post_type ) ) ? 'term-' . $main_topic->slug : '';

Comment: @Leslie: Your code does exactly the same as my mentioned above. Your block of code only differs in its notation format (`if shorthand` to prevent sourcecode to bloat). Downside of `if shorthand`: it might be a bit confusing to read to beginners

Comment: I'm trying to edit someone else's work, that's why. And i just started out on PHP. Really appreciated your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$additional_classes[] = ( is_object( $main_topic ) && 1221 != $post->ID && !is_singular( $Theme->News->post_type ) ) ? 'term-' . $main_topic->slug : '';
```

hope that solves it.

Comment: That's what i did. Is there another ways to use operators to put them 425 and 1221 into the same line?

Thanks!

Comment: && (1221 != $post->ID || 425 != $post->ID ) &&